# Saving the installation log generated from setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

Is there a way to save the output that is generated during the installation of a program being installed using setup.py ? I want to write this into the setup.py script itself, not in the terminal when i run setup.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the `setup()` function is called, redirect `sys.stdout` ( and `sys.stderr` to the log file. )

Make sure you revert back the `stdout` ( and `stderr` ) to their default references and print the contents of log file to `stdout` as well.

Your setup.py should look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

stdout = sys.stdout
stderr = sys.stderr

log_file = open('log', 'w')
sys.stdout = log_file
sys.stderr = log_file

setup ( 
        ...  ,
        ...
      )

# Make sure to close the log file. You could also use with to surround the setup()
# To ensure log file is closed in the event of exception.
log_file.close()

sys.stdout = stdout
sys.stderr = stderr

with open('log', 'r') as log_file:
    sys.stdout.write(log_file.read())
```

Comment: This almost works.  It missed a compiler warning when installing mysql-python into a python 2.7 virtual enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following in terminal or powershell

```
pyhton.exe setup.py >> logfile.txt
```

this should append all console output to logfile.txt